# Texture showing up in rendered view but pink color in texture view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, 3d-view, shaders

I have a mountain textured with three different textures by using two mix shaders. I am using Blender 2.80.75. In texture view I can only see a pink color but in render view I see the correct result. Is this a bug or what? Thanks in advance
[image: Textured mode viewport]
[image: Node setup]

Comment: Blender must have lost the path to your image(s), you need to reload your images in the Image Texture node(s)

Comment: @moonboots I already did that, but when I display each texture separately using node wrangler it shows correct result and also in render view mode it displays correct result, the problem occurs only in texture view mode